# Sequence item 0: expected str instance, bool found (Odoo 14)

Tags: python, odoo

I am getting an error "in _get_report_values
map(lambda x: x.ref, docs.account_invoice_ids)) or ', '.join(
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bool found".

```
data['test'] = docs.type == 'type1' and ', '.join(
            map(lambda x: x.reference, docs.acc)) or ', '.join(
            map(lambda x: x.name, docs.acc))
```

Any help please?

Comment: Error trace and a clearer snippet may be helpful. Btw in `data['test']` you are assigning a boolean value. Are you sure you need a boolean there instead of a string, like the error says?

Comment: @Valerio Preti , I need string not boolean , how can I fix it ? Thanks.

Comment: One formatting note, it's a good idea to break up expressions into logical chunks rather than breaking them arbitrarily. In this case, that would mean enclosing the whole in an extra pair of parentheses, then breaking the lines ahead of the `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply, I don't actually have much information about what you are trying to do, but this may be a solution:

```py
data['test'] = ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.reference, docs.acc)) if docs.type == 'type1' else ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.name, docs.acc))
```

Using this syntax you join `x.reference` if the document type is `type1` otherwise you join `x.name`

**Edit:**
As @sabik pointed out, you can also simplify the statement using a generators instead of the map function.
If the document type is equal for the whole collection you can simplify your statement in this way:

```py
data['test'] = ', '.join(x.reference for x in docs.acc) if docs.type == 'type1' else ', '.join(x.name for x in docs.acc)
```

Also, for readability sake, you can also try something like this:

```py
doc_attr = "reference" if docs.type == "type1" else "name"
data["test"] = ", ".join(getattr(x, doc_attr) for x in docs.acc)
```

Otherwise if the type change for each "x" you can use

```py
data['test'] = ', '.join(x.reference if x.type == 'type1' else x.name for x in docs.acc)
```

Comment: We can further simplify this by rewriting the `map` functions as generator expressions: `data['test'] = ', '.join(x.reference for x in docs.acc) if docs.type == 'type1' else ', '.join(x.name for x in docs.acc)`

Comment: That's assuming the `.type` field is indeed on the whole collection and not on each individual item; if it's on each individual item, it'd be something like: `data['test'] = ', '.join(x.reference if x.type == 'type1' else x.name for x in docs.acc)`